# Spotify login: canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify-action://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme spotify-action"

Tags: ios, xcode, spotify

I'm trying to read spotify music in my app in swift.
I followed the beginner user and the youtube tutorial ["iOS Swift Tutorial: Stream Music from Spotify"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GeO00YdJ3cE) but I can't success login.

I have this error and don't know why :

```
canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify-action://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme spotify-action"
```

I have a ClientID, SecretID, BundleID, and URI in my developper spotify account.

I precise that is not a problem of LSApplicationQueriesSchemes : "The LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key is not needed since Beta 10 do not support Spotify App Authentication."
How to resolve this ?

Comment: As it said : "The LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key is not needed since Beta 10 do not support Spotify App Authentication." 
So it's not a duplicate question. Thanks

Comment: It is a duplicate. The error you are asking about (`canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify-action://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme spotify-action"`) is in fact a duplicate of the linked question. If you are having other auth issues with Spotify then you need to ask a different question specific to those issues and not the issue with opening a url when you haven't whitelisted the scheme in your info.plist.